# Docker container running but not being listed and cannot be stopped

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I'm relatively new to docker and I've been having a really strange problem.

The docker setup I have below runs perfectly, however though there seems to be an instance that is always running even after stopping and removing all containers and quitting the docker application.

When I access localhost in my browser, My app is always live and running.

I've tried running docker-compose stop ; docker-compose rm to stop and remove all container.

'docker-compose ps' and 'docker ps' both show no containers running at all. But whenever I access localhost, my app is there live and running.

Like i said i have tried quitting the docker application (I'm running on mac). i tried restarting the machine and the app would still be running.

The weird thing is when i check to see which if any processes are using port 80 (thus making my app accessible via localhost) by running 'sudo lsof -i tcp:80' the list is empty.

I'm new to docker and I know there must be something I'm overlooking. 
Thanks in advance, any help and ideas are welcomed.

Here is my folder structure: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH45F.jpg)

The Dockerfile for my app:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./app/
    container_name: nuxt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '1880:1880'
    command: 'npm run start'

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
```

Comment: Caching issue? Can you add output of `ps aux | grep containerd-shim` please? Although if nothing is listening on `80` I don't see how it can be serving.

Comment: the output is diizzayy          1638   0.0  0.0  4278280    816 s001  S+   10:37AM   0:00.00 grep containerd-shim

Comment: So, there are no containers running :) What about `ps aux | grep nginx`?

Comment: that's what has me so confused, I can't think of any reason why it would be serving especially after stopping and removing all containers then quitting docker

Comment: `ps aux | grep nginx` returns `diizzayy          1649   0.0  0.0  4268040    780 s001  S+   10:41AM   0:00.00 grep nginx`

Comment: Sure it's not caching? Hard refresh your browser?

Comment: I'll give that a try, just a second

Comment: Wow, that actually worked Lol. it was driving me crazy.